# File Browser GUI

Tags: java, tree, file-system, swing, gui

*FileBro* is a basic GUI based File Browser.

[image]

### FileBro Functionality

- Directory tree - shows the file system roots at start-up, but is otherwise built lazily as the user browses around the file system.  *FileBro* displays a progress bar as it is loading new entries.
- The file list (a table) displays a list of the directories and files in the current directory tree selection.  Sort by clicking on the column header.
- Buttons - all use the `Desktop` class for their functionality.  If the action cannot be completed, a meaningful reason should by displayed in a `JEditorPane` error message.

  - `Locate` - opens the parent directory of the currently selected file.
  - `Open` - launches whatever application is the default consumer for that file type.
  - `Edit` - opens the file for edit in the default consumer.
  - `Print` - prints the file using the default consumer.
- Details on the selected file are displayed below the buttons.

---

Does the current functionality work as per above description?

### FileBrowser.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

import java.net.URL;

/**
A basic File Browser.  Requires 1.6+ for the Desktop & SwingWorker
classes, amongst other minor things.

Includes support classes FileTableModel & FileTreeCellRenderer.

@TODO Bugs
<li>Fix keyboard focus issues - especially when functions like
rename/delete etc. are called that update nodes & file lists.
<li>Needs more testing in general.

@TODO Functionality
<li>Double clicking a directory in the table, should update the tree
<li>Move progress bar?
<li>Add other file display modes (besides table) in CardLayout?
<li>Menus + other cruft?
<li>Implement history/back
<li>Allow multiple selection
<li>Add file search

@author Andrew Thompson
@version 2011-06-08
@see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784
@license LGPL
*/
class FileBrowser {

    /** Title of the application */
    public static final String APP_TITLE = "FileBro";
    /** Used to open/edit/print files. */
    private Desktop desktop;
    /** Provides nice icons and names for files. */
    private FileSystemView fileSystemView;

    /** currently selected File. */
    private File currentFile;

    /** Main GUI container */
    private JPanel gui;

    /** File-system tree. Built Lazily */
    private JTree tree;
    private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;

    /** Directory listing */
    private JTable table;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    /** Table model for File[]. */
    private FileTableModel fileTableModel;
    private ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener;
    private boolean cellSizesSet = false;
    private int rowIconPadding = 6;

    /* File controls. */
    private JButton openFile;
    private JButton printFile;
    private JButton editFile;

    /* File details. */
    private JLabel fileName;
    private JTextField path;
    private JLabel date;
    private JLabel size;
    private JCheckBox readable;
    private JCheckBox writable;
    private JCheckBox executable;
    private JRadioButton isDirectory;
    private JRadioButton isFile;

    /* GUI options/containers for new File/Directory creation.  Created lazily. */
    private JPanel newFilePanel;
    private JRadioButton newTypeFile;
    private JTextField name;

    public Container getGui() {
        if (gui==null) {
            gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
            gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));

            fileSystemView = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
            desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

            JPanel detailView = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));

            table = new JTable();
            table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
            table.setShowVerticalLines(false);

            listSelectionListener = new ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
                    int row = table.getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();
                    setFileDetails( ((FileTableModel)table.getModel()).getFile(row) );
                }
            };
            table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);
            JScrollPane tableScroll = new JScrollPane(table);
            Dimension d = tableScroll.getPreferredSize();
            tableScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)d.getWidth(), (int)d.getHeight()/2));
            detailView.add(tableScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            // the File tree
            DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
            treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

            TreeSelectionListener treeSelectionListener = new TreeSelectionListener() {
                public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent tse){
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node =
                        (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tse.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
                    showChildren(node);
                    setFileDetails((File)node.getUserObject());
                }
            };

            // show the file system roots.
            File[] roots = fileSystemView.getRoots();
            for (File fileSystemRoot : roots) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(fileSystemRoot);
                root.add( node );
                File[] files = fileSystemView.getFiles(fileSystemRoot, true);
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file));
                    }
                }
                //
            }

            tree = new JTree(treeModel);
            tree.setRootVisible(false);
            tree.addTreeSelectionListener(treeSelectionListener);
            tree.setCellRenderer(new FileTreeCellRenderer());
            tree.expandRow(0);
            JScrollPane treeScroll = new JScrollPane(tree);

            // as per trashgod tip
            tree.setVisibleRowCount(15);

            Dimension preferredSize = treeScroll.getPreferredSize();
            Dimension widePreferred = new Dimension(
                200,
                (int)preferredSize.getHeight());
            treeScroll.setPreferredSize( widePreferred );

            // details for a File
            JPanel fileMainDetails = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,2));
            fileMainDetails.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,6,0,6));

            JPanel fileDetailsLabels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,2,2));
            fileMainDetails.add(fileDetailsLabels, BorderLayout.WEST);

            JPanel fileDetailsValues = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,2,2));
            fileMainDetails.add(fileDetailsValues, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            fileDetailsLabels.add(new JLabel("File", JLabel.TRAILING));
            fileName = new JLabel();
            fileDetailsValues.add(fileName);
            fileDetailsLabels.add(new JLabel("Path/name", JLabel.TRAILING));
            path = new JTextField(5);
            path.setEditable(false);
            fileDetailsValues.add(path);
            fileDetailsLabels.add(new JLabel("Last Modified", JLabel.TRAILING));
            date = new JLabel();
            fileDetailsValues.add(date);
            fileDetailsLabels.add(new JLabel("File size", JLabel.TRAILING));
            size = new JLabel();
            fileDetailsValues.add(size);
            fileDetailsLabels.add(new JLabel("Type", JLabel.TRAILING));

            JPanel flags = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING,4,0));

            isDirectory = new JRadioButton("Directory");
            flags.add(isDirectory);

            isFile = new JRadioButton("File");
            flags.add(isFile);
            fileDetailsValues.add(flags);

            JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
            // mnemonics stop working in a floated toolbar
            toolBar.setFloatable(false);

            JButton locateFile = new JButton("Locate");
            locateFile.setMnemonic('l');

            locateFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Locate: " + currentFile.getParentFile());
                        desktop.open(currentFile.getParentFile());
                    } catch(Throwable t) {
                        showThrowable(t);
                    }
                    gui.repaint();
                }
            });
            toolBar.add(locateFile);

            openFile = new JButton("Open");
            openFile.setMnemonic('o');

            openFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Open: " + currentFile);
                        desktop.open(currentFile);
                    } catch(Throwable t) {
                        showThrowable(t);
                    }
                    gui.repaint();
                }
            });
            toolBar.add(openFile);

            editFile = new JButton("Edit");
            editFile.setMnemonic('e');
            editFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    try {
                        desktop.edit(currentFile);
                    } catch(Throwable t) {
                        showThrowable(t);
                    }
                }
            });
            toolBar.add(editFile);

            printFile = new JButton("Print");
            printFile.setMnemonic('p');
            printFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    try {
                        desktop.print(currentFile);
                    } catch(Throwable t) {
                        showThrowable(t);
                    }
                }
            });
            toolBar.add(printFile);

            // Check the actions are supported on this platform!
            openFile.setEnabled(desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN));
            editFile.setEnabled(desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.EDIT));
            printFile.setEnabled(desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.PRINT));

            flags.add(new JLabel("::  Flags"));
            readable = new JCheckBox("Read  ");
            readable.setMnemonic('a');
            flags.add(readable);

            writable = new JCheckBox("Write  ");
            writable.setMnemonic('w');
            flags.add(writable);

            executable = new JCheckBox("Execute");
            executable.setMnemonic('x');
            flags.add(executable);

            int count = fileDetailsLabels.getComponentCount();
            for (int ii=0; ii<count; ii++) {
                fileDetailsLabels.getComponent(ii).setEnabled(false);
            }

            count = flags.getComponentCount();
            for (int ii=0; ii<count; ii++) {
                flags.getComponent(ii).setEnabled(false);
            }

            JPanel fileView = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));

            fileView.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            fileView.add(fileMainDetails,BorderLayout.CENTER);

            detailView.add(fileView, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(
                JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                treeScroll,
                detailView);
            gui.add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JPanel simpleOutput = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
            progressBar = new JProgressBar();
            simpleOutput.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.EAST);
            progressBar.setVisible(false);

            gui.add(simpleOutput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        }
        return gui;
    }

    public void showRootFile() {
        // ensure the main files are displayed
        tree.setSelectionInterval(0,0);
    }

    private TreePath findTreePath(File find) {
        for (int ii=0; ii<tree.getRowCount(); ii++) {
            TreePath treePath = tree.getPathForRow(ii);
            Object object = treePath.getLastPathComponent();
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)object;
            File nodeFile = (File)node.getUserObject();

            if (nodeFile==find) {
                return treePath;
            }
        }
        // not found!
        return null;
    }

    private void showErrorMessage(String errorMessage, String errorTitle) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            gui,
            errorMessage,
            errorTitle,
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
            );
    }

    private void showThrowable(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            gui,
            t.toString(),
            t.getMessage(),
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
            );
        gui.repaint();
    }

    /** Update the table on the EDT */
    private void setTableData(final File[] files) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (fileTableModel==null) {
                    fileTableModel = new FileTableModel();
                    table.setModel(fileTableModel);
                }
                table.getSelectionModel().removeListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);
                fileTableModel.setFiles(files);
                table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);
                if (!cellSizesSet) {
                    Icon icon = fileSystemView.getSystemIcon(files[0]);

                    // size adjustment to better account for icons
                    table.setRowHeight( icon.getIconHeight()+rowIconPadding );

                    setColumnWidth(0,-1);
                    setColumnWidth(3,60);
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(120);
                    setColumnWidth(4,-1);
                    setColumnWidth(5,-1);
                    setColumnWidth(6,-1);
                    setColumnWidth(7,-1);
                    setColumnWidth(8,-1);
                    setColumnWidth(9,-1);

                    cellSizesSet = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setColumnWidth(int column, int width) {
        TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
        if (width<0) {
            // use the preferred width of the header..
            JLabel label = new JLabel( (String)tableColumn.getHeaderValue() );
            Dimension preferred = label.getPreferredSize();
            // altered 10->14 as per camickr comment.
            width = (int)preferred.getWidth()+14;
        }
        tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(width);
        tableColumn.setMaxWidth(width);
        tableColumn.setMinWidth(width);
    }

    /** Add the files that are contained within the directory of this node.
    Thanks to Hovercraft Full Of Eels for the SwingWorker fix. */
    private void showChildren(final DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
        tree.setEnabled(false);
        progressBar.setVisible(true);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        SwingWorker<Void, File> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, File>() {
            @Override
            public Void doInBackground() {
                File file = (File) node.getUserObject();
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    File[] files = fileSystemView.getFiles(file, true); //!!
                    if (node.isLeaf()) {
                        for (File child : files) {
                            if (child.isDirectory()) {
                                publish(child);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    setTableData(files);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<File> chunks) {
                for (File child : chunks) {
                    node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(child));
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressBar.setVisible(false);
                tree.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }

    /** Update the File details view with the details of this File. */
    private void setFileDetails(File file) {
        currentFile = file;
        Icon icon = fileSystemView.getSystemIcon(file);
        fileName.setIcon(icon);
        fileName.setText(fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(file));
        path.setText(file.getPath());
        date.setText(new Date(file.lastModified()).toString());
        size.setText(file.length() + " bytes");
        readable.setSelected(file.canRead());
        writable.setSelected(file.canWrite());
        executable.setSelected(file.canExecute());
        isDirectory.setSelected(file.isDirectory());

        isFile.setSelected(file.isFile());

        JFrame f = (JFrame)gui.getTopLevelAncestor();
        if (f!=null) {
            f.setTitle(
                APP_TITLE +
                " :: " +
                fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(file) );
        }

        gui.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Significantly improves the look of the output in
                    // terms of the file names returned by FileSystemView!
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch(Exception weTried) {
                }
                JFrame f = new JFrame(APP_TITLE);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                FileBrowser FileBrowser = new FileBrowser();
                f.setContentPane(FileBrowser.getGui());

                try {
                    URL urlBig = FileBrowser.getClass().getResource("fb-icon-32x32.png");
                    URL urlSmall = FileBrowser.getClass().getResource("fb-icon-16x16.png");
                    ArrayList<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
                    images.add( ImageIO.read(urlBig) );
                    images.add( ImageIO.read(urlSmall) );
                    f.setIconImages(images);
                } catch(Exception weTried) {}

                f.pack();
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
                f.setVisible(true);

                FileBrowser.showRootFile();
            }
        });
    }
}

/** A TableModel to hold File[]. */
class FileTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private File[] files;
    private FileSystemView fileSystemView = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    private String[] columns = {
        "Icon",
        "File",
        "Path/name",
        "Size",
        "Last Modified",
        "R",
        "W",
        "E",
        "D",
        "F",
    };

    FileTableModel() {
        this(new File[0]);
    }

    FileTableModel(File[] files) {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        File file = files[row];
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return fileSystemView.getSystemIcon(file);
            case 1:
                return fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(file);
            case 2:
                return file.getPath();
            case 3:
                return file.length();
            case 4:
                return file.lastModified();
            case 5:
                return file.canRead();
            case 6:
                return file.canWrite();
            case 7:
                return file.canExecute();
            case 8:
                return file.isDirectory();
            case 9:
                return file.isFile();
            default:
                System.err.println("Logic Error");
        }
        return "";
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.length;
    }

    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return ImageIcon.class;
            case 3:
                return Long.class;
            case 4:
                return Date.class;
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
                return Boolean.class;
        }
        return String.class;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columns[column];
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return files.length;
    }

    public File getFile(int row) {
        return files[row];
    }

    public void setFiles(File[] files) {
        this.files = files;
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}

/** A TreeCellRenderer for a File. */
class FileTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

    private FileSystemView fileSystemView;

    private JLabel label;

    FileTreeCellRenderer() {
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
        fileSystemView = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(
        JTree tree,
        Object value,
        boolean selected,
        boolean expanded,
        boolean leaf,
        int row,
        boolean hasFocus) {

        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)value;
        File file = (File)node.getUserObject();
        label.setIcon(fileSystemView.getSystemIcon(file));
        label.setText(fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(file));
        label.setToolTipText(file.getPath());

        if (selected) {
            label.setBackground(backgroundSelectionColor);
            label.setForeground(textSelectionColor);
        } else {
            label.setBackground(backgroundNonSelectionColor);
            label.setForeground(textNonSelectionColor);
        }

        return label;
    }
}
```

The `FileBrowser.java` source code is around 650 lines.

### Also

- Here are 2 icons for the app. (but it will run OK without them).  They will be used if found in the same directory as the classes.  The icons use `Color.WHITE` to represent unselected table rows & tree nodes, so those are invisible in a web page with white background.  ;)

  1. `fb-icon-16x16.png` [image: fm-icon-16x16.png]
  2. `fb-icon-32x32.png` [image: fm-icon-32x32.png]
- Any other comments/tips/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I so far have not been able to reproduce your error. Are there any actions which usually precipitates the problem?

Comment: @Andrew: I see that you've added a bounty to this question. Does that mean that you're still getting the same error, that changing the SwingWorker didn't fix things? Or if not, what problems are still issues with the updated code?  /Pete

Comment: @HFOE:  Your changes to the SwingWorker fixed that problem just fine.  I'm trying to get more testing in general.  (To spot the next 7 bugs.)

Comment: @HFOE:  I was just thinking about the problems with this thread earlier.  The code is getting too big to make substantial additions & still post at SO.  Also I was thinking to maybe use this code as my first foray into SourceForge.  So yes, that is a big possibility.  Having said that, I'll let it run till near the end of the bounty period, just to see if any new & brilliant points come up.  Though, (whispers) it'd be hard for anybody to top the advice offered before the bounty was posted. ;)

Comment: @Andrew: I wonder if you're at the stage where you'd be better served by creating a project with multiple classes likely in several packages and posting it on SourceForge for all to contribute to. I'm not saying that the problems currently present aren't worth solving, just that perhaps the complexity of these problems are beyond what stackoverflow is best at solving. This would be a neat project for all to contribute to in an organized way.  **Sorry**, I edited this to add `version control` by deleting my original comment just before you added yours and adding mine just afterward.

Comment: Just wondering why you need to click a folder in the file system view to see if it's expandable. i.e., the "+" icon doesn't appear next to a folder until you click it

Comment: @ryvantage The example might be tweaked to display the files and directories of a newly opened branch, but **also count the files at the top  level of each directory found.** BNI - it was already getting very close to the character limit for a question. ;)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This code concerns me:

```
  SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
     @Override
     public String doInBackground() {
        tree.setEnabled(false);
        progressBar.setVisible(true);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        File file = (File) node.getUserObject();
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
           File[] files = fileSystemView.getFiles(file, true);
           if (node.isLeaf()) {
              for (File child : files) {
                 if (child.isDirectory()) {
                    node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(child));
                 }
              }
           }
           setTableData(files);
        }
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressBar.setVisible(false);
        tree.setEnabled(true);
        return "done";
     }
  };
  worker.execute();
```

as you're making Swing calls to a JProgressBar off of the EDT.  Best to start the progress bar before the SwingWorker and end it in the done method. Either that or add a PropertyChangeListener to the SwingWorker and end the progress bar when the worker's state property is StateValue.DONE.

Another issue is that you're using a DefaultMutableTreeNode, and per the API, concurrency care must be taken when using this since you do appear to be using this in more than one thread:

> This is not a thread safe class.If you intend to use a DefaultMutableTreeNode (or a tree of TreeNodes) in more than one thread, you need to do your own synchronizing. A good convention to adopt is synchronizing on the root node of a tree.

**EDIT**
One way to *possibly* get DefaultMutableTreeNode at least out of the equation is to add nodes to it in one thread only, the EDT, by using SwingWorker's publish/process.  For example:

```
   private void showChildren(final DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
      tree.setEnabled(false);
      progressBar.setVisible(true);
      progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

      SwingWorker<Void, File> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, File>() {
         @Override
         public Void doInBackground() {
            File file = (File) node.getUserObject();
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
               File[] files = fileSystemView.getFiles(file, true); //!!
               if (node.isLeaf()) {
                  for (File child : files) {
                     if (child.isDirectory()) {
                        publish(child);
                     }
                  }
               }
               setTableData(files);
            }
            return null;
         }

         @Override 
         protected void process(List<File> chunks) {
            for (File child : chunks) {
               node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(child));
            }
         }

         @Override
         protected void done() {
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressBar.setVisible(false);
            tree.setEnabled(true);
         }
      };
      worker.execute();
   }
```

Comment: It is the call to `fileSystemView.getFiles(file, true);` that is the problem - it takes some time for drives that have been powered down, or the Network folder.  It stands to reason that if I should not be updating GUI elements in the doInBG() method, I also should not be adding nodes to the tree.  Right?  Or does the last para. & quote address that problem?

Comment: @Andrew: please see edit to my post above with updated SwingWorker that uses publish and process in order to add to node on the EDT.

Comment: Right, the model can only be changed on the EDT.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: also, are you logging your program's state when the error occurs? Any helpful information in the messages?

Comment: @HFOE: Implemented your more rigorous treatment of SwingWorker.  Have not seen any NPEs since (fingers crossed).  See edit for latest code.  As to the stacktraces, they never indicated a line in FileManager.java, they were so infrequent that I would often only realize they occurred as the CLI was disappearing from behind the closing app.  Always either an AIOOBE on the table or NPE on table or tree.  I suspect they are now sorted.

Comment: Andrew Thompson +1, but that's typically Windows OS issue, if I tried that inside Local Network, where is Intranet access controled by Domain Controller or Novell (Ldap), then by click to the Network Icon freeze Desktop for long time (same as from Windows OS), sure there maybe doesn't exists direct/correct way fot that, how to redirect it if icon conntains Network to the background task, (ignore that if is only for native English Localization), because looks like as nonsense to get all Labels from Windows FullLocalizations and from Windows Language Pack for Network Label

Comment: Since this improvement to the SwingWorker solved the most pervasive bug in the original code (now edited out of existence), I have marked it 'correct'.  Thanks for your help.  The latest FileBro code is added.

Answer (score 23):

Mac OS X 10.5 and Ubuntu 10.04: Repeated non-fatal NPE on delete.

Addendum: In line 441, `findTreePath()` always returns `null`, because `currentFile.getParentFile()` returns the path to the file, not the file itself. In effect, the path cannot match itself. I don't see an obvious work-around.

Addendum: I am unable to find an acceptable solution. I suspect the problem revolves around the dichotomy between view (`JTree`) and model (`DefaultTreeModel`). In particular, `findTreePath()` is searching among visible rows rather than the nodes of the tree model. It may prove useful to implement `TreeModel` explicitly, as shown in this [`FileTreeModel`](https://dzone.com/articles/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-). It may also help to abstract view-model conversion methods analogous to those provided by [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html).

As an alternative approach, consider [`org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html), pictured below. It accepts the [`FileTreeModel`](https://dzone.com/articles/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-), mentioned earlier. By extending [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html), it uses the familiar [renderer and editor schema](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) via a convenient [`RowModel`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/RowModel.html) interface similar to `TableModel`. Most importantly, it provides [`convertRowIndexToModel()`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/etable/ETable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29), as well as [`convertRowIndexToView()`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/etable/ETable.html#convertRowIndexToView%28int%29). The [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) method `getValueAt()` is overridden to call [`convertRowIndexToModel()`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/etable/ETable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29), making the selection listener in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841183/access-tree-object-in-netbeans-outline/2841582#2841582) straightforward. The JAR is independent, small (~230 KiB) and stable; it may be found in the NetBeans distribution:

> `NetBeans/platform/modules/org-netbeans-swing-outline.jar`

[image: outline view]

Addendum: `FileBrowser` version 2011-06-08 operates correctly on both systems cited above.

```
currentFile: /temp.txt
parentPath: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at FileManager.deleteFile(FileManager.java:443)
  at FileManager.access$1000(FileManager.java:56)
  at FileManager$9.actionPerformed(FileManager.java:306)
  at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
  at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
  at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
  at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
  at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
  at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6374)
  at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
  at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6139)
  at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2085)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4736)
  at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2143)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4566)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4621)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4282)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4212)
  at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2129)
  at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4566)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:680)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:86)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:639)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:637)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
  at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:653)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:651)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:650)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: I've never seen an application that dynamically changes the icon of the frame. Would this not be confusing if you are trying to find your applicaton by icon on the task bar or when you use Alt-tab to find the application. I would suggest you can just create a FileManager icon and not change it.

Comment: See also [`PanelBrowser`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15104660/230513).

Answer (score 19):

This is the last edit of the code before I decided to turn FileMan(ager) into FileBro(wser) (**FileBro** is coming to an edit on the original question, 'real soon now').  This version of FileMan is posted here for the benefit of the people who want to extend this (very incomplete, buggy) code in that direction.

[image]

### FileManager.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

import java.net.URL;

/**
A basic File Manager.  Requires 1.6+ for the Desktop & SwingWorker
classes, amongst other minor things.

Includes support classes FileTableModel & FileTreeCellRenderer.

@TODO Bugs
<li>Still throws occasional AIOOBEs and NPEs, so some update on
the EDT must have been missed.
<li>Fix keyboard focus issues - especially when functions like
rename/delete etc. are called that update nodes & file lists.
<li>Needs more testing in general.

@TODO Functionality
<li>Implement Read/Write/Execute checkboxes
<li>Implement Copy
<li>Extra prompt for directory delete (camickr suggestion)
<li>Add File/Directory fields to FileTableModel
<li>Double clicking a directory in the table, should update the tree
<li>Move progress bar?
<li>Add other file display modes (besides table) in CardLayout?
<li>Menus + other cruft?
<li>Implement history/back
<li>Allow multiple selection
<li>Add file search

@author Andrew Thompson
@version 2011-06-01
@see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110
@license LGPL
*/
class FileManager {

    /** Title of the application */
    public static final String APP_TITLE = "FileMan";
    /** Used to open/edit/print files. */
    private Desktop desktop;
    /** Provides nice icons and names for files. */
    private FileSystemView fileSystemView;

    /** currently selected File. */
    private File currentFile;

    /** Main GUI container */
    private JPanel gui;

    /** File-system tree. Built Lazily */
    private JTree tree;
    private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;

    /** Directory listing */
    private JTable table;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    /** Table model for File[]. */
    private FileTableModel fileTableModel;
    private ListSelectionListener listSelectionListener;
    private boolean cellSizesSet = false;
    private int rowIconPadding = 6;

    /* File controls. */
    private JButton openFile;
    private JButton printFile;
    private JButton editFile;
    private JButton deleteFile;
    private JButton newFile;
    private JButton copyFile;
    /* File details. */
    private JLabel fileName;
    private JTextField path;
    private JLabel date;
    private JLabel size;
    private JCheckBox readable;
    private JCheckBox writable;
    private JCheckBox executable;
    private JRadioButton isDirectory;
    private JRadioButton isFile;

    /* GUI options/containers for new File/Directory creation.  Created lazily. */
    private JPanel newFilePanel;
    private JRadioButton newTypeFile;
    private JTextField name;

    public Container getGui() {
        if (gui==null) {
            gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
            gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));

            fileSystemView = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
            desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

            JPanel detailView = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
            //fileTableModel = new FileTableModel();

            table = new JTable();
            table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
            table.setShowVerticalLines(false);

            listSelectionListener = new ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
                    int row = table.getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();
                    setFileDetails( ((FileTableModel)table.getModel()).getFile(row) );
                }
            };
            table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);
            JScrollPane tableScroll = new JScrollPane(table);
            Dimension d = tableScroll.getPreferredSize();
            tableScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int)d.getWidth(), (int)d.getHeight()/2));
            detailView.add(tableScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            // the File tree
            DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
            treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

            TreeSelectionListener treeSelectionListener = new TreeSelectionListener() {
                public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent tse){
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode node =
                        (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tse.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
                    showChildren(node);
                    setFileDetails((File)node.getUserObject());
                }
            };

            // show the file system roots.
            File[] roots = fileSystemView.getRoots();
            for (File fileSystemRoot : roots) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(fileSystemRoot);
                root.add( node );
                //showChildren(node);
                //
                File[] files = fileSystemView.getFiles(fileSystemRoot, true);
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file));
                    }
                }
                //
            }

            tree = new JTree(treeModel);
            tree.setRootVisible(false);
            tree.addTreeSelectionListener(treeSelectionListener);
            tree.setCellRenderer(new FileTreeCellRenderer());
            tree.expandRow(0);
            JScrollPane treeScroll = new JScrollPane(tree);

            // as per trashgod tip
            tree.setVisibleRowCount(15);

            Dimension preferredSize = treeScroll.getPreferredSize();
            Dimension widePreferred = new Dimension(
                200,
                (int)preferredSize.getHeight());
            treeScroll.setPreferredSize( widePreferred );

            // details for a File
            JPanel fileMainDetails = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,2));
            fileMainDetails.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,6,0,6));

            JPanel fileDetailsLabels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,2,2));
            fileMainDetails.add(fileDetailsLabels, BorderLayout.WEST);

            JPanel fileDetailsValues = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,2,2));
            fileMainDetails.add(fileDetailsValues, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            fileDetailsLabels.add(new JLabel("File", JLabel.TRAILING));
            fileName = new JLabel();
            fileDetailsValues.add(fileName);
            fileDetailsLabels.add(new JLabel("Path/name", JLabel.TRAILING));
            path = new JTextField(5);
            path.setEditable(false);
            fileDetailsValues.add(path);
            fileDetailsLabels.add(new JLabel("Last Modified", JLabel.TRAILING));
            date = new JLabel();
            fileDetailsValues.add(date);
            fileDetailsLabels.add(new JLabel("File size", JLabel.TRAILING));
            size = new JLabel();
            fileDetailsValues.add(size);
            fileDetailsLabels.add(new JLabel("Type", JLabel.TRAILING));

            JPanel flags = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING,4,0));
            isDirectory = new JRadioButton("Directory");
            isDirectory.setEnabled(false);
            flags.add(isDirectory);

            isFile = new JRadioButton("File");
            isFile.setEnabled(false);
            flags.add(isFile);
            fileDetailsValues.add(flags);

            int count = fileDetailsLabels.getComponentCount();
            for (int ii=0; ii<count; ii++) {
                fileDetailsLabels.getComponent(ii).setEnabled(false);
            }

            JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
            // mnemonics stop working in a floated toolbar
            toolBar.setFloatable(false);

            openFile = new JButton("Open");
            openFile.setMnemonic('o');

            openFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    try {
                        desktop.open(currentFile);
                    } catch(Throwable t) {
                        showThrowable(t);
                    }
                    gui.repaint();
                }
            });
            toolBar.add(openFile);

            editFile = new JButton("Edit");
            editFile.setMnemonic('e');
            editFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    try {
                        desktop.edit(currentFile);
                    } catch(Throwable t) {
                        showThrowable(t);
                    }
                }
            });
            toolBar.add(editFile);

            printFile = new JButton("Print");
            printFile.setMnemonic('p');
            printFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    try {
                        desktop.print(currentFile);
                    } catch(Throwable t) {
                        showThrowable(t);
                    }
                }
            });
            toolBar.add(printFile);

            // Check the actions are supported on this platform!
            openFile.setEnabled(desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN));
            editFile.setEnabled(desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.EDIT));
            printFile.setEnabled(desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.PRINT));

            toolBar.addSeparator();

            newFile = new JButton("New");
            newFile.setMnemonic('n');
            newFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    newFile();
                }
            });
            toolBar.add(newFile);

            copyFile = new JButton("Copy");
            copyFile.setMnemonic('c');
            copyFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    showErrorMessage("'Copy' not implemented.", "Not implemented.");
                }
            });
            toolBar.add(copyFile);

            JButton renameFile = new JButton("Rename");
            renameFile.setMnemonic('r');
            renameFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    renameFile();
                }
            });
            toolBar.add(renameFile);

            deleteFile = new JButton("Delete");
            deleteFile.setMnemonic('d');
            deleteFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    deleteFile();
                }
            });
            toolBar.add(deleteFile);

            toolBar.addSeparator();

            readable = new JCheckBox("Read  ");
            readable.setMnemonic('a');
            //readable.setEnabled(false);
            toolBar.add(readable);

            writable = new JCheckBox("Write  ");
            writable.setMnemonic('w');
            //writable.setEnabled(false);
            toolBar.add(writable);

            executable = new JCheckBox("Execute");
            executable.setMnemonic('x');
            //executable.setEnabled(false);
            toolBar.add(executable);

            JPanel fileView = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));

            fileView.add(toolBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            fileView.add(fileMainDetails,BorderLayout.CENTER);

            detailView.add(fileView, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(
                JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                treeScroll,
                detailView);
            gui.add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JPanel simpleOutput = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
            progressBar = new JProgressBar();
            simpleOutput.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.EAST);
            progressBar.setVisible(false);

            gui.add(simpleOutput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        }
        return gui;
    }

    public void showRootFile() {
        // ensure the main files are displayed
        tree.setSelectionInterval(0,0);
    }

    private TreePath findTreePath(File find) {
        for (int ii=0; ii<tree.getRowCount(); ii++) {
            TreePath treePath = tree.getPathForRow(ii);
            Object object = treePath.getLastPathComponent();
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)object;
            File nodeFile = (File)node.getUserObject();

            if (nodeFile==find) {
                return treePath;
            }
        }
        // not found!
        return null;
    }

    private void renameFile() {
        if (currentFile==null) {
            showErrorMessage("No file selected to rename.","Select File");
            return;
        }

        String renameTo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(gui, "New Name");
        if (renameTo!=null) {
            try {
                boolean directory = currentFile.isDirectory();
                TreePath parentPath = findTreePath(currentFile.getParentFile());
                DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode =
                    (DefaultMutableTreeNode)parentPath.getLastPathComponent();

                boolean renamed = currentFile.renameTo(new File(
                    currentFile.getParentFile(), renameTo));
                if (renamed) {
                    if (directory) {
                        // rename the node..

                        // delete the current node..
                        TreePath currentPath = findTreePath(currentFile);
                        System.out.println(currentPath);
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode =
                            (DefaultMutableTreeNode)currentPath.getLastPathComponent();

                        treeModel.removeNodeFromParent(currentNode);

                        // add a new node..
                    }

                    showChildren(parentNode);
                } else {
                    String msg = "The file '" +
                        currentFile +
                        "' could not be renamed.";
                    showErrorMessage(msg,"Rename Failed");
                }
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                showThrowable(t);
            }
        }
        gui.repaint();
    }

    private void deleteFile() {
        if (currentFile==null) {
            showErrorMessage("No file selected for deletion.","Select File");
            return;
        }

        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
            gui,
            "Are you sure you want to delete this file?",
            "Delete File",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
            );
        if (result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            try {
                System.out.println("currentFile: " + currentFile);
                TreePath parentPath = findTreePath(currentFile.getParentFile());
                System.out.println("parentPath: " + parentPath);
                DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode =
                    (DefaultMutableTreeNode)parentPath.getLastPathComponent();
                System.out.println("parentNode: " + parentNode);

                boolean directory = currentFile.isDirectory();
                boolean deleted = currentFile.delete();
                if (deleted) {
                    if (directory) {
                        // delete the node..
                        TreePath currentPath = findTreePath(currentFile);
                        System.out.println(currentPath);
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode =
                            (DefaultMutableTreeNode)currentPath.getLastPathComponent();

                        treeModel.removeNodeFromParent(currentNode);
                    }

                    showChildren(parentNode);
                } else {
                    String msg = "The file '" +
                        currentFile +
                        "' could not be deleted.";
                    showErrorMessage(msg,"Delete Failed");
                }
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                showThrowable(t);
            }
        }
        gui.repaint();
    }

    private void newFile() {
        if (currentFile==null) {
            showErrorMessage("No location selected for new file.","Select Location");
            return;
        }

        if (newFilePanel==null) {
            newFilePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));

            JPanel southRadio = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0,2,2));
            newTypeFile = new JRadioButton("File", true);
            JRadioButton newTypeDirectory = new JRadioButton("Directory");
            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            bg.add(newTypeFile);
            bg.add(newTypeDirectory);
            southRadio.add( newTypeFile );
            southRadio.add( newTypeDirectory );

            name = new JTextField(15);

            newFilePanel.add( new JLabel("Name"), BorderLayout.WEST );
            newFilePanel.add( name );
            newFilePanel.add( southRadio, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        }

        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
            gui,
            newFilePanel,
            "Create File",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            try {
                boolean created;
                File parentFile = currentFile;
                if (!parentFile.isDirectory()) {
                    parentFile = parentFile.getParentFile();
                }
                File file = new File( parentFile, name.getText() );
                if (newTypeFile.isSelected()) {
                    created = file.createNewFile();
                } else {
                    created = file.mkdir();
                }
                if (created) {

                    TreePath parentPath = findTreePath(parentFile);
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode =
                        (DefaultMutableTreeNode)parentPath.getLastPathComponent();

                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        // add the new node..
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file);

                        TreePath currentPath = findTreePath(currentFile);
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode =
                            (DefaultMutableTreeNode)currentPath.getLastPathComponent();

                        treeModel.insertNodeInto(newNode, parentNode, parentNode.getChildCount());
                    }

                    showChildren(parentNode);
                } else {
                    String msg = "The file '" +
                        file +
                        "' could not be created.";
                    showErrorMessage(msg, "Create Failed");
                }
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                showThrowable(t);
            }
        }
        gui.repaint();
    }

    private void showErrorMessage(String errorMessage, String errorTitle) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            gui,
            errorMessage,
            errorTitle,
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
            );
    }

    private void showThrowable(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            gui,
            t.toString(),
            t.getMessage(),
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
            );
        gui.repaint();
    }

    /** Update the table on the EDT */
    private void setTableData(final File[] files) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (fileTableModel==null) {
                    fileTableModel = new FileTableModel();
                    table.setModel(fileTableModel);
                }
                table.getSelectionModel().removeListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);
                fileTableModel.setFiles(files);
                table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);
                if (!cellSizesSet) {
                    Icon icon = fileSystemView.getSystemIcon(files[0]);

                    // size adjustment to better account for icons
                    table.setRowHeight( icon.getIconHeight()+rowIconPadding );

                    setColumnWidth(0,-1);
                    setColumnWidth(3,60);
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setMaxWidth(120);
                    setColumnWidth(4,-1);
                    setColumnWidth(5,-1);
                    setColumnWidth(6,-1);
                    setColumnWidth(7,-1);
                    setColumnWidth(8,-1);
                    setColumnWidth(9,-1);

                    cellSizesSet = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setColumnWidth(int column, int width) {
        TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
        if (width<0) {
            // use the preferred width of the header..
            JLabel label = new JLabel( (String)tableColumn.getHeaderValue() );
            Dimension preferred = label.getPreferredSize();
            // altered 10->14 as per camickr comment.
            width = (int)preferred.getWidth()+14;
        }
        tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(width);
        tableColumn.setMaxWidth(width);
        tableColumn.setMinWidth(width);
    }

    /** Add the files that are contained within the directory of this node.
    Thanks to Hovercraft Full Of Eels. */
    private void showChildren(final DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {
        tree.setEnabled(false);
        progressBar.setVisible(true);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        SwingWorker<Void, File> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, File>() {
            @Override
            public Void doInBackground() {
                File file = (File) node.getUserObject();
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    File[] files = fileSystemView.getFiles(file, true); //!!
                    if (node.isLeaf()) {
                        for (File child : files) {
                            if (child.isDirectory()) {
                                publish(child);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    setTableData(files);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<File> chunks) {
                for (File child : chunks) {
                    node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(child));
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressBar.setVisible(false);
                tree.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }

    /** Update the File details view with the details of this File. */
    private void setFileDetails(File file) {
        currentFile = file;
        Icon icon = fileSystemView.getSystemIcon(file);
        fileName.setIcon(icon);
        fileName.setText(fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(file));
        path.setText(file.getPath());
        date.setText(new Date(file.lastModified()).toString());
        size.setText(file.length() + " bytes");
        readable.setSelected(file.canRead());
        writable.setSelected(file.canWrite());
        executable.setSelected(file.canExecute());
        isDirectory.setSelected(file.isDirectory());

        isFile.setSelected(file.isFile());

        JFrame f = (JFrame)gui.getTopLevelAncestor();
        if (f!=null) {
            f.setTitle(
                APP_TITLE +
                " :: " +
                fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(file) );
        }

        gui.repaint();
    }

    public static boolean copyFile(File from, File to) throws IOException {

        boolean created = to.createNewFile();

        if (created) {
            FileChannel fromChannel = null;
            FileChannel toChannel = null;
            try {
                fromChannel = new FileInputStream(from).getChannel();
                toChannel = new FileOutputStream(to).getChannel();

                toChannel.transferFrom(fromChannel, 0, fromChannel.size());

                // set the flags of the to the same as the from
                to.setReadable(from.canRead());
                to.setWritable(from.canWrite());
                to.setExecutable(from.canExecute());
            } finally {
                if (fromChannel != null) {
                    fromChannel.close();
                }
                if (toChannel != null) {
                    toChannel.close();
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        return created;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Significantly improves the look of the output in
                    // terms of the file names returned by FileSystemView!
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch(Exception weTried) {
                }
                JFrame f = new JFrame(APP_TITLE);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();
                f.setContentPane(fileManager.getGui());

                try {
                    URL urlBig = fileManager.getClass().getResource("fm-icon-32x32.png");
                    URL urlSmall = fileManager.getClass().getResource("fm-icon-16x16.png");
                    ArrayList<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
                    images.add( ImageIO.read(urlBig) );
                    images.add( ImageIO.read(urlSmall) );
                    f.setIconImages(images);
                } catch(Exception weTried) {}

                f.pack();
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
                f.setVisible(true);

                fileManager.showRootFile();
            }
        });
    }
}

/** A TableModel to hold File[]. */
class FileTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private File[] files;
    private FileSystemView fileSystemView = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    private String[] columns = {
        "Icon",
        "File",
        "Path/name",
        "Size",
        "Last Modified",
        "R",
        "W",
        "E",
        "D",
        "F",
    };

    FileTableModel() {
        this(new File[0]);
    }

    FileTableModel(File[] files) {
        this.files = files;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        File file = files[row];
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return fileSystemView.getSystemIcon(file);
            case 1:
                return fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(file);
            case 2:
                return file.getPath();
            case 3:
                return file.length();
            case 4:
                return file.lastModified();
            case 5:
                return file.canRead();
            case 6:
                return file.canWrite();
            case 7:
                return file.canExecute();
            case 8:
                return file.isDirectory();
            case 9:
                return file.isFile();
            default:
                System.err.println("Logic Error");
        }
        return "";
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.length;
    }

    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return ImageIcon.class;
            case 3:
                return Long.class;
            case 4:
                return Date.class;
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
                return Boolean.class;
        }
        return String.class;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columns[column];
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return files.length;
    }

    public File getFile(int row) {
        return files[row];
    }

    public void setFiles(File[] files) {
        this.files = files;
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}

/** A TreeCellRenderer for a File. */
class FileTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

    private FileSystemView fileSystemView;

    private JLabel label;

    FileTreeCellRenderer() {
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setOpaque(true);
        fileSystemView = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(
        JTree tree,
        Object value,
        boolean selected,
        boolean expanded,
        boolean leaf,
        int row,
        boolean hasFocus) {

        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)value;
        File file = (File)node.getUserObject();
        label.setIcon(fileSystemView.getSystemIcon(file));
        label.setText(fileSystemView.getSystemDisplayName(file));
        label.setToolTipText(file.getPath());

        if (selected) {
            label.setBackground(backgroundSelectionColor);
            label.setForeground(textSelectionColor);
        } else {
            label.setBackground(backgroundNonSelectionColor);
            label.setForeground(textNonSelectionColor);
        }

        return label;
    }
}
```

### Addendum

In the end I decided that I did not need anything more than a file browser.  When it came to *managing* files, simply opening the parent directory & using the OS' inbuilt functionality to make new files, rename them, copy or delete them, as well as change the flags, would suffice.

That not only got rid of many of the remaining bugs, but also removed any possibility that a user's lawyers might contact me about how my software deleted everything on their client's LAN when they asked it to delete a symbolic link.  ;)

Comment: access to the Network works +1, what did you change, :-) and sleep too :-)

Answer (score 14):

Andrew, it looks good. I use XP and JDK6.07 and haven't had any problems when browsing or using New/Delete/Rename functionality.

A couple of comments:

1. The Icon header and all the check box headers are truncated and show "...". The following fixed it for me:

   ```
   //            width = (int)preferred.getWidth()+10;  
                 width = (int)preferred.getWidth()+14;
   ```
2. I found the reading the text of a selected node difficult. It is black text on a dark blue background. The JTable was much easier to read with white text on a dark blue background. I see the default tree renderer also supports text selection/non-selection colours.
3. If you really want to give users a bang for their buck, then maybe when deleting a directory you can prompt the user to see if they want to delete all the files first before deleting the directory.

Answer (score 7):

It works on WinXP and Win2008_64b (JRE64b) and everything looks correct. For deepest tests, just click on each accessible `Component`s, without any errors.

But as I mentioned, selection on Network hanged (on WinXP, no errors, killed from IDE), JProgresBar too, in contrast with win2008, there ProgresBar works and just short time and diplay right contents of network tree.

[image: Network_WinXP _SP3 JRE 1.6.025]

My assumption about the Active Directory daemon (next only AD) is that I have local admin access for Intranet and it looks like as from end user PC by local admin account AD some*** restricted view for Network's tree, AD some*** managed this access, and I can't access the AD setting because that's an outsourced service.

1. WinXP SP3 SK LanguagePack (that isn't full localizations as Spain, Germany, ...) logged here by a local admin account click to Network icon in JTree died without any errors as I described twice.
2. Win7 64b SK (sorry no time for deepest analyses, only logged here by local admin account and runs your child out of console) icon in JTree returns null to the JTable and click by Open JButton and returns just a Win7 error.

   [image: FilemanNetworkWin7.JPG]
3. Win2008 is access managed by AD accessible context, because there isn't possible to create local account (internal rules).

Answer (score 7):

There is a bug: when the table is sorted, the mapping between the selection model row index and the table model row index is broken and the buttons end up operating on other files.

The `ListSelectionListener` should correct that:

```
int row = table.getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();
RowSorter sorter = table.getRowSorter();
if ( sorter != null ) {
    row = sorter.convertRowIndexToModel( row );                            
}
```